# Why is the word *the* necessary?

Tags: definite-article, determiners, zero-article

Why do I have to use **the** in following phrase?

> What are **the** problems ....

For example

> What are the problems John is facing while riding a bike?
>
> What are the problems Smith is facing while solving a puzzle?
>
> What are the problems Jeff is facing while reconciling his financials?

Comment: The . . . is the giveaway. If you give a fair example (eg 'What are the problems associated with answering queries on ELU?'), you see that it's a _specific_ set of problems being referred to. Another determiner could be used: 'What are some [of the] problems associated with answering queries on ELU?'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth examples have been provided

Comment: Many languages do without it, so it's not strictly necessary. It's somewhat useful in certain situations, but English would work just fine without *the/a*, just possibly losing a little precision or requiring slightly longer constructs in rare, specific situations.

Comment: Note that you wouldn't have to use "the" if you changed the way the verb is written: "What problems does John face while riding a bike? What problems arise while Smith is solving a puzzle? What problems is Jeff facing when reconciling his finances?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

John is **a** poor man who has **a lot** of problems. **Some** of **his** problems have to do with riding **a** bike. **Some** of **his** problems have to do with money, **some** with **his** children, **some** with **his** boring job, and **some** problems he has because he would rather live in **the** countryside than **the** crowded, smoggy city, which also happens to set off **his** asthma. Luckily, John's wife is **the** apple of **his** eye and **the** light of **his** life. So he has **no** problems with her. **Her** only problem with him is that he loves her so much.

Of **all**  **those** problems, which **ones** do you want to know about?

**Those** he must face while riding **a** bike? Then **that** is **a** specific set of problems represented by **the** word **the**. For **a** small word, it is very important.

If you don't want to hear about **all** of **his**  **many** problems, ask only about **those** problems he has while riding **a** bike (not **the** red bike, but **any** bike.)

> I am interested in knowing about **the** problems John has while riding **a** bike.

**All** of **the** bold-type words are **determiners**. **A** determiner is **a** modifying word that determines **the** kind of reference a noun or noun group has: a? the? some? all? none? one? these? those? his? her? their? no? [**Here**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/determiner) is **a** list of determiners.

Comment: Liked the way of your explanation.

Answer (score 2):

John is facing a specific set of problems while riding a bike, and you are asking for that specific set. You are interested in *the* problems John is facing while riding a bike.

Now, while "What are problems John is facing while riding a bike" is ungrammatical, do note that you could ask "What are some [of the] problems John is facing while riding a bike". Just keep in mind that the corresponding answer would then be a *partial* list.

Answer (score 1):

Ditto many other answers.

Another way to put it is, "The word 'the' is necessary because it is a convention in English." It may not actually convey any information or make the sentence more clear, but it is required by the language. That's just how it is. It's like, Why do men wear a tie when they want to look more formal and dressed up? What useful purpose does a tie serve? Probably none, it's just a convention.

Answer (score -1):

If you use "What is the problem" vs "What is a problem" it might be clearer.
In the one without the "the" you're asking for a definition of the word problem. In the other one you're asking for the problem one might have.

Comment: "What is a problem" doesn't ask for a definition in this context, but might outside of it.